# Can not install dotnet-ignore tool globally

Tags: .net-core

I'm using dotnet version 2.1.503, and I'm trying to run the command:

`dotnet tool install dotnet-ignore --global`

But I'm getting an error saying error

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Response status code does not indicate success: 401
>   (Unauthorized).

What's going on?

Comment: It really sounds like a networking issue on your end. Can you reproduce the problem on another machine or from another network?

Comment: I had a similar problem. For me the problem was that I am under a corporate proxy-server. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15463892/6560579) answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the nuget machine wide configurations that require authorization. See the answer to this question: [Permanently remove machine-wide package source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877115/permanently-remove-machine-wide-package-source/54895984#54895984)